# I have problems with the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have problems with the bibliography

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{bibfile.bib} %this command appear in the blue color not like the others 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\bibliography` command should go where you want the bibliography to be output, so definitely *after* `\begin{document}`. Also the `.bib` extension should be removed.

Comment: also to what @egreg said: `\bibliographystyle{}` needs some sort of switch, such as `plain` or `unsrt`

Answer (score 1):

Before using the bibliography (.bib) file, you just need to mention which style you are going to use in the \bibliographystyle{}.

There exists many bibliography styles including plain, ieee, ieeetr apalike, unsrt, ama, cj, nar etc.

Moreover, before using this, you just need to add the .bst file in your current working directory.

This may be helpful to you.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % This style is meant for IEEE. You can use anything based on your requirements.
\bibliography{bibfile} % Don't use the extension .bib after specifying the name of your reference database.
\end{document}
```